# Error during MySQL encryption, Code: 3185. "Can't find master key from keyring (...)"

Tags: mysql, encryption

I was trying to configure MySQL keyring plugin and I did the following:

• Made sure that *keyring_file.dll* is present either in *C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin* directory.

• added to my.ini:

```
innodb_file_per_table = 1
early-plugin-load = keyring_file.dll
```

• restarted MySQL service and even the whole dedicated Windows Server
• run the following SQL(s):

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ENCRYPTION='Y';
```

and I got the following error:

> Error Code: 3185. Can't find master key from keyring, please check in
>   the server log if a keyring plugin is loaded and initialized
>   successfully.

Very strange, because I did the same on other server with the same version of MySQL and it worked.

I executed this:

```
SELECT @@plugin_dir
```

and it shows right directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin\

WHY do I get that error ??

Comment: looks like you haven't generated a key for [mysql keyring file plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keyring-file-plugin.html)

Comment: I don't remember that I ever did anything like that on the other server. Strange thing is that MySQL is installed on that server in Program Files, but on this server it is installed in Program Files (x86). The other server has a file at "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\keyring\keyring" which keeps InnoDBKey. So what do you suggest, should I run that keyring_key_generate function to generate that key ?

Comment: As I thought it didn't work. I tried to run that SQL "SELECT keyring_key_generate('MyKey', 'AES', 32);", but I got "Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION safety.keyring_key_generate does not exist" error.

Comment: So how do you make it load that damn keyring extension ?

Comment: Accually I was wrong about the version. On server 2 (encryption working good) the version of MySQL is 5.7.32 64-bit, but on server 1 (encryption not working) the version is MySQL 5.7.22 32-bit, even though Windows Server 2012 is 64-bit. I think this is the problem, ins't it?

Answer (score 0):

What is your MySQL Version?

I find the following 'solution' and i will try upgrade mine 5.7.20 to 5.7.22:

> Posted by developer:
>
> Fixed in 5.7.22, 8.0.4, 9.0.0.
>
> Cosmetic change to
>   error message. No changelog entry needed.

Maybe it will solve your problem.